# hadoop CustomInputFormat Not getting invoked

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a custom input format and configured that in job. Still that inputformat is not getting invoked. I have kept some SOP's to get printed while running the code but none of them are printing. Even when I comment the custom inputformat in the driver class still the output remains same. Where am I missing ?

DriverClass

```
public class TestDriver {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf,"Custom Format");
        job.setMapperClass(CustomInputFormatmapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CustomInputFormatReducer.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(CustomInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.getConfiguration().set("fs.file.impl", "com.learn.WinLocalFileSystem");
        String inputPath="In\\VISA_Details.csv";
        Path inPath=new Path(inputPath);
        String outputPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hadoop learning\\output\\run1";
        Path outPath=new Path(outputPath);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inPath );
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);

        System.out.println(job.waitForCompletion(true));


    }
}
```

### CUSTOM INPUTFORMAT

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

public class CustomInputFormat extends TextInputFormat{

    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
    {
        System.out.println(" ------------ INSIDE createRecordReader()--------------");
        return new CustomRecordReader();
    }
}
```

### CUSTOM RECORDREADER

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader;

public class CustomRecordReader extends RecordReader {

    private CompressionCodecFactory compressionCodecs;
    private final int NLINESTOPROCESS = 3;
    private long start;
    private long pos;
    private long end;
    private LineReader in;
    private int maxLineLength;
    private LongWritable key;
    private Text value;

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit inputsplit,TaskAttemptContext taskattemptcontext) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(" ---------- INSIDE INITILISE:  THIS IS NOT PRINTING----------");
        FileSplit split = (FileSplit)inputsplit;
        Configuration job = taskattemptcontext.getConfiguration();
        maxLineLength = job.getInt("mapred.linerecordreader.maxlength", 2147483647);
        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();
        Path file = split.getPath();
        compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(job);
        CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(file);
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());
        boolean skipFirstLine = false;
        if(codec != null)
        {
            in = new LineReader(codec.createInputStream(fileIn), job);
            end = 9223372036854775807L;
        } else
        {
            if(start != 0L)
            {
                skipFirstLine = true;
                start--;
                fileIn.seek(start);
            }
            in = new LineReader(fileIn, job);
        }
        if(skipFirstLine)
            start += in.readLine(new Text(), 0, (int)Math.min(2147483647L, end - start));
        pos = start;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println(" ---------- INSIDE nextKeyValue()------------");
        if(key==null){
            key = new LongWritable();
        }
        if(value==null){
            value = new Text();
        }
        key.set(pos);
        value.clear();

        final Text newLine = new Text("\n");
        Text newVal = new Text();
         int newSize = 0;

        for(int i =0;i<NLINESTOPROCESS;i++){
             Text v = new Text();

             while(pos<end){
                 newSize = in.readLine(v, maxLineLength,Math.max((int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end-pos),maxLineLength));
                 value.append(v.getBytes(),0, v.getLength());
                 value.append(newLine.getBytes(),0, newLine.getLength());

                 if (newSize == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    pos += newSize;
                    if (newSize < maxLineLength) {
                        break;
                    }

             }
        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

### MAPPER CLASS

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class CustomInputFormatmapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, LongWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text val, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String value = val.toString();
        String[] totalRows = value.split("\n");
        int count =totalRows.length;

        context.write(new LongWritable(Long.valueOf(count)), new LongWritable(1L));

    }
}
```

### REDUCER CLASS

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CustomInputFormatReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable> {

    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<LongWritable> val, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(" --------REDUCER--------");
        long count =0;
        for(LongWritable vals: val){
            count++;
        }
        context.write(key, new LongWritable(count));
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you think it doesn't work because you don't see the print statements?

Comment: @DebD, Have you tried putting `job.setjarByClass(TestDriver.class)`?

Comment: @irW: I m running it in eclipse and not in the VM. So the SOP statements should be shown.

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker: I am not running it as a job so I dont need to put that thing. Even if I put that, then also the custom inputformat is not getting picked.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the windows filesystem you are trying, it's the only spot in the code that I am unfamiliar with? Can you show us the logs of this run?

Comment: The logs are having everything which I put as SOP in driver/mapper/reducer class except the customInputFormat class. By using the windows filesystem, you can run a MR job in eclipse without having a VM.

Comment: yes but extract the relevant parts, are there any exceptions?

Comment: Ok, I have found the error. But need some help to resolve this.
When I put @Override in my CustomInputFormat class's createRecordReader() method, then I am getting error "please implement or override the supertype method". Is my implementation wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as this will help others to get through the problem which I faced. There was a problem with the package which I was importing.
Mentioning the mistakes which I did.

### CUSTOMINPUTFORMAT CLASS

1) Missed the @Override annotation
2) Imported from import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit instead of  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;

### CUSTOMRECORDREADER

1) Imports were done from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.* and not from  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;